# Navbar not hiding on ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to hide a navbar depending on if the user is logged in or not. But the navbar is not hiding when i change the `$scope.loggedIn` variable. Why?

View:

```
<nav>
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <!-- Logged in -->
    <div ng-show="loggedIn">   <!-- this one displays all the time -->
      Navbar logged in
      <a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Log out</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Logged out-->
    <div ng-hide="loggedIn">   <!-- this one never displays -->
      Navbar logged out
      <a href="#" ng-click="login()">Log in</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'userService',
   function($scope, $state, userService) {
      $scope.loggedIn = userService.isLoggedIn();

      // been trying this, but it does not work
      $scope.$watch('userService.login()', function(newVal) {
        $scope.loggedIn = newVal;
      });

      $scope.login = function() {
        userService.login();
        $state.go('home');
      };

      $scope.logout = function() {
        userService.logout();
        $state.go('login');
      };
   }
 ]);
```

Service:

```
.factory('userService', ['$http', function($http) {
   var loggedIn = false;

   return {
     isLoggedIn: function() {
        return loggedIn;
     }, 
     login: function() {
        loggedIn = true;
     },
     logout: function() {
        loggedIn = false;
     }
  };

}]);
```

Comment: the way it looks (without seeing more code), it appears as though you are setting a value in an instance returned by a factory, and then immediately transitioning to a new page via `$state.go` which is then, theoretically, creating a new instance from the factory, with the default `loggedIn=false` set.  If you want `userService` to be a singleton, use `.service` instead of `.factory`.

Comment: Ok Ill try it... Did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the controller you are binding a boolean primitive to `$scope.loggedIn`. This does not change when you change the variable in your service.

The way your watch is setup is incorrect. It can be made to work by using the code below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
 
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'userService',
   function($scope, userService) {
      $scope.$watch(userService.isLoggedIn, function(newVal) {
        $scope.loggedIn = newVal;
      });
     
      $scope.login = function() {
        userService.login();
      };

      $scope.logout = function() {
        userService.logout();
      };
   }
 ]);

app.factory('userService', ['$http', function($http) {
   var loggedIn = false;

   return {
     isLoggedIn: function() {
        return loggedIn;
     }, 
     login: function() {
        loggedIn = true;
     },
     logout: function() {
        loggedIn = false;
     }
  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <!-- Logged in -->
    <div ng-show="loggedIn">
      Navbar logged in
      <a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Log out</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Logged out-->
    <div ng-hide="loggedIn">
      Navbar logged out
      <a href="#" ng-click="login()">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You could also expose a user object from your user service that contains the login status of the user:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'userService',
  function($scope, userService) {
    $scope.user = userService.user;
    
    $scope.login = function() {
      userService.login();
    };
    $scope.logout = function() {
      userService.logout();
    };
  }
]);

app.factory('userService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    var user = {loggedIn: false};

    return {
      user: user,
      login: function() {
        user.loggedIn = true;
      },
      logout: function() {
        user.loggedIn = false;
      }
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <!-- Logged in -->
    <div ng-show="user.loggedIn">
      Navbar logged in
      <a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Log out</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Logged out-->
    <div ng-hide="user.loggedIn">
      Navbar logged out
      <a href="#" ng-click="login()">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code for redirecting to another page after return call of login method from factory

```
 $scope.login = function() {
        userService.login().then(function(data){;
        $state.go('home');
       });
      };
```